# Attempt to read property "password" on null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I tried to use Hash and I kept getting this error:

```
Class "App\Http\Controllers\Hash" not found
```

I also tried importing Hash, but then I got another error.

`Attempt to read property "password" on null`

Here's my code from the *UserController.php* file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    function login(Request $req)
    {
       $user= User::where(['email'=>$req->email])->first();
       if($user || Hash::check($req->password,$user->password))
       {
           return "Username or password is not matched";

       }
       else{
           $req->session()->put('user',$user);
           return redirect('/');
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `||`, if the first operand evaluates to a truthy value, the evaluation is short-circuited, because the outcome will always be `true` as soon as any operand is `true`.

In your case, the `$user` variable may be `null` (if the email is not found in the database). Because `null` is a falsy value, the evaluation goes on to the next operand, where you try to read `$user->password`.

In your case, you want to evaluate the 2nd operand only if `$user` isn't null, so you should replace your `||` with an `&&`.

You can find the documentation for this behavior on the following page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
if ($user && Hash::check($req->password,$user->password))
//        ^^ <--- use "&&" instead of "||"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the `$req` and `$user` value.
It happen because one of those variable has null value. So when you try to get password property it will return those error.

```
function login(Request $req)
{
   $user= User::where(['email'=>$req->email])->first();

   // Uncomment this following statement to check is those 2 variable has value or not
   // dd($req, $user); 

   if($user || Hash::check($req->password,$user->password))
   {
       return "Username or password is not matched";

   }
   else{
       $req->session()->put('user',$user);
       return redirect('/');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the error in expected logic. It should be

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where([
            'email' => $request->email
        ])
        ->first();

    // correct logic would be read as 'if there is no user in database found by provided email 
    // OR 
    // if there is that kind of user but provided password is not one stored in database, return error'
    if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user?->password)) {
        return "Username or password is not matched";
    }

    // otherwise do what ever need to be done
    $request->session()->put('user', $user);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

If you are not using PHP 8 then substitute null safe operator with checking if object is not null before trying to execute method on variable

i.e.

```
// instead $user?->password
// it could be
if (!is_null($user)) { /** do something with $user->password */}
```

But it is minor thing, most important is to have correct logic similar to what I put above in code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should check if the user does not exist or if the password provided doesn't match the existing values in the database
Update your if statement to look like this

```
 if(!$user || (!Hash::check($req->password,$user->password)))
```

Full code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    function login(Request $req)
    {
       $user= User::where(['email'=>$req->email])->first();
       if(!$user || (!Hash::check($req->password,$user->password)))
       {
           return "Username or password is not matched";

       }
       else{
           $req->session()->put('user',$user);
           return redirect('/');
       }
    }
}
```